# Zoom entire layout for xlarge

Tags: android, layout, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb

After going through a meticulous design and layout for layout-large (targeting the Galaxy Tab) I've discovered there is way too much empty space on the xlarge XOOM and things appear too small and cluttered, even though I used dip and sp everywhere.  What I want to do is take the same large design and blow it up for xlarge so everything takes up the same screen proportions on the xlarge screen.  I've started going down the path of using @dimens to increase the font sizes, heights and widths, paddings and margins of everything depending on the screen, but this approach looks like it will be hard to maintain as there are hundreds of such dimensions.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to automatically zoom in the entire layout so it takes up the full XOOM real estate.  By the magic of math it has turned out that the large-hdpi measurements just need to be doubled for the xlarge-mdpi screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed document on how to handle XOOM layouts on the Motorola developer site. http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/motorola-xoom-tablet-programming-tips/

Comment: Yes, and on the Text and Screen size section they recommend using size-dependent @dimen which is the approach I'm trying to avoid.